# Creating Swiper Gesture back and forth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.2

I am using xcode 4.2. Here is my herarchy

```
Navigation COntroller (No toolbars) -> ViewController1 -> ViewController2 -> ViewController3 ->ViewController4
```

I have added `swipe gestures` in 1-3 Controllers and have used push using Left Swipe.

Now This is one direction only. How can i do it bi-directional. I want to go to ViewController1 from ViewController4. I have tried adding another `SwipeGesture` assigning right but it don't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the direction property of UISwipeGestureRecognizer and using the bit wise operator with different directions should work.

There are existing questions on this. It's well explained there.

[How to recognize swipe in all 4 directions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181774/recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions)

[Setting direction for UISwipeGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319209/setting-direction-for-uiswipegesturerecognizer)

Answer (score 0):

You might look into this post [Setting direction for UISwipeGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319209/setting-direction-for-uiswipegesturerecognizer)
Besides this, if you receive the notification you can see in which controller you are and if you in controller 1 and it is a left swipe push controller 4 onto the stack. But beware of the fact that we are talking about a stack. So every time you push a controller the stack grows. It might be to have your controllers initiated on first use and than keep a reference. You can   bring the corresponding view into place if you detect a swipe.