# Unable to detect swipe position from bottom to top in iOS

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have already tried by this code but gesture not detect.

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *mSwipeUpRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(up_downBtn_waytosalon)];
 [mSwipeUpRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
 [self.duration_distanceView addGestureRecognizer:mSwipeUpRecognizer];
```

Comment: So, `up_downBtn_waytosalon` method is not getting called?

Comment: yes.. up_downBtn_waytosalon method was not called but now its working fine.. thanks for help :)

Comment: I guess, its because colon ':' was missing after selector name.

Answer (score 0):

First Off, you need to always pass the gesture recognizer to your selector, otherwise you can't determine the state of your gesture.

Other than that first check if that view has `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`, I'm guessing that view doesn't get any user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize swipe gesture like this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *mSwipeUpRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(up_downBtn_waytosalon:)];
      mSwipeUpRecognizer.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp);
[self.duration_distanceView addGestureRecognizer:mSwipeUpRecognizer];
```

Implement the gesture action like this:

```
- (void) up_downBtn_waytosalon:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
  if ( sender.direction | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp )
    NSLog(@"Its swipe up");
}
```

Hope this code helps.

Comment: don't copy paste another code if you do this just mention that I taken the code from here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181774/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions

Answer (score 0):

YOUR `duration_distanceView` view is `imageView` then add below line your code.

```
self.duration_distanceView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Try this code :

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *mSwipeUpRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(up_downBtn_waytosalon)];
self.duration_distanceView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [mSwipeUpRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
 [self.duration_distanceView addGestureRecognizer:mSwipeUpRecognizer];
```