# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not responding to Up

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following `UIGestureRecognizer` which detects swipe up properly

```
- (void) addGestureRecognizer {
    _swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    [_swipeRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
    [_swipeRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_swipeRecognizer];
}

- (void) didSwipe:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"didSwipe");
}
```

I then modified the direction to include left and right

```
[_swipeRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
```

and it no longer responds to swiping up (swiping left or right works). What am I doing wrong? (tried on simulator, iphone5, ipad3)

**Note**: I do not need to detect the actual direction of the swipe. I just need to know there is a swipe. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recognize swipe in all 4 directions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181774/recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions)

Comment: this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3415323/1387720) is better than the linked post above. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *_swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    [_swipeRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [_swipeRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_swipeRecognizer];

    _swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    [_swipeRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
    [_swipeRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_swipeRecognizer];
```

**EDIT**

As @LearnCocos2D [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420078/detect-when-uigesturerecognizer-is-up-down-left-and-right-cocos2d/7760927#7760927)  " *Apparently each UISwipeGestureRecognizer can only detect the swipe in the given direction. Even though the direction flags could be OR'ed together the UISwipeGestureRecognizer ignores the additional flags.* "

And As per your "**Note**: *I do not need to detect the actual direction of the swipe. I just need to know there is a swipe.*", You just need to detect swipe not the direction so combining right-left as one and up-down as other gesture will work.

Comment: this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3415323/1387720) is a much better explanation than the one everyone seems to be referencing. thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

swipeGesture is discree gesture, and swipe up and down is two different gesture.
You must create 4 gesture and send it to one action.

```
- (void) addGestureRecognizer {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeLeft setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [swipeRight setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

}

- (void) didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    NSLog(@"didSwipe");
}
```

Comment: that is not correct. `direction` is a bit mask. Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181774/recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions?rq=1