# How to make swipe gesture recogniser detect both left and right directions?

Tags: swift

I've written a code and did an IB action from the main storyboard to the view controller for a swipe gesture action.

```
@IBAction func swipeToSwitchScheme(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.direction == .right{
            switchCurrentScheme()
        }

        else if sender.direction == .left {
            print("swiped left")
        }
    }
```

However, it seems like it can only detect .right gesture and not left. Is there something wrong with how I execute the gestureRecogniser?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
@IBAction func swipeToSwitchScheme(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.direction == .right {
            switchCurrentScheme()
        }
    }
    @IBAction func swipeLeft(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.direction == .left {
            print("swipe left")
            switchCurrentSchemeLeft()
        }
    }
```

I got it like this but only the right gesture is recognised

Comment: Show the code where you have added `GestureRecognizer` to view.

Comment: Oh I did it in storyboard, I didnt do it programmatically

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7760927/1187415, you need separate swipe gesture recognizers for each direction.

Comment: Oh, I've tried that before. But in doing so it cancels each other out. Both recognisers are not working or printing anything.

Comment: Thats impossible. They cannot be recognized at the same moment.

Comment: Hmm still not working for me. Could it be that I have other interactive objects in the view as well like buttons and such.

Comment: @Wilson add two gestures from storyboard as mentioned in third answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215117/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions) thread

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, apparently if you wanna add two gesture recognisers in the same view, you'll have to define both of their directions in viewDidLoad. So put both of the recogniser's outlets to the swift file and then set them to their respective directions in viewDidLoad.